# Como retirar uma informação em um texto?

Tags: javascript, node.js

gostaria de buscar e extrair uma string que esteja entre tags. Utilizando somente JavaScript com Node.

Exemplo: Extrair informação dentro de uma tag qualquer e salvar em alguma variável.

Eu não estou sabendo implementar um código para isso. Não sei se consegui ser claro.

Exemplo2 é o que eu estou tentando fazer.
Buscar e salvar os nomes dos professores que estão nesta página. Percebi que todos estão entre as tags header2...

```
    const url = 'http://www.ppg-educacao.uff.br/novo/index.php/corpo-docente'
const axios = require('axios')

axios.get(url).then(response =>{
    const funcionarios = response.data
    console.log(funcionarios) //Somente para verificar as informações da página foram extraidas.
    //Eu gostaria de salvar o nome de todos os professores, e percebi que todos estão entre a tag <h2>...
    const tag = funcionarios.querySelector("h2")
    const conteudoDeTextoDaTag = tag.textContent
    console.log(conteudoDeTextoDaTag)
});
```

Comment: Olá Daniel, pesquise sobre a função `substring` e sobre *regular expressions* que pode te ajudar. Além disso, poste na pergunta seu código, o que já fez

Comment: Dê um exemplo prático disso pra facilitar o entendimento. Da forma que você descreveu a pergunta está vaga

Comment: Vou melhorar isso.

Comment: Sim, tenta melhorar e dar exemplos. Se for `HTML` você pode usar um parser. Se for `XML` já é outro tipo de biblioteca.

Comment: Joguei lá uma alteração, espero ter ficado mais claro...

Comment: Nesse caso a `const funcionarios` é um array de h2? se for, vc pode iterar sobre ele  para pegar cada elemento.

Comment: Não, no caso, essa constante recebe todo o código html da página.

Comment: Editei minha resposta ali em baixo.. vê se te ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considere utilizar um `parser HTML` como o [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio). Para o seu exemplo ficaria parecido com:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

console.log($('h2').text());
```

Com ele você pode utilizar seletores `CSS` para extrair informações relevantes do `HTML` em questão.

Comment: Seu exemplo me ajudou a adaptar para o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Eai, tente fazer assim:

`trechoRetirado= '' + trechoRetirado;`

e depois, `trechoRetirado.substring (13);`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338357/string-manipulation-with-javascript-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado a todos pelo tempo oferecido a esta duvida e pelo conhecimento a mim passado.
Agradecido e a questão foi resolvida pela resposta do Sorack.